# Why is the closing body tag HTML5 being inserted at the bottom of the page when I close it before footer?

Tags: css, html

I am attempting to create a footer tag to change the background color of it.

```
footer {
display: block;
background-color: #92a8d1 !important;   
}

<footer>
<div class="container-fluid" name="footer">
</div>
</footer>
```

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFiSu.jpg)

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnXAK.jpg)

Could someone help me fix the code for CSS color displays on the footer?

Comment: footer tag should be inside body

Comment: Footer is in body now, I am displaying the custom css at the top, but the color don't change. name="footer1" # and . don't work. Hmm, I'll try to figure this out I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I cant comment yet so will just answer here. You might not have a height for your footer, that is why it is not showing. Try setting a height like:

```
footer {
/*display: block;*/ /*remove this, footer is already a block element*/
height: 200px;
background-color: #92a8d1 !important;  
}
```

This might help. You can send a sample/plunk of your code in order for us to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the footer does have to be inside the body. After the body comes only the closing html-Tag.

If you want a footer for your page, add it before the closing body Tag. This is the same behaviour as if you would have a p-tag in another p-tag. The browser auto corrects your errors and places them next to each other.

Answer (score -1):

If I got your question right this should work :

```
<footer style="background-color: #92a8d1;">
<div class="container-fluid"> </div>
</footer>
```

I think the background-color is overwritten by an other style.

Comment: Please tell why this should work better than the exposed question's snippet, and eventually add references to documentation.